# ExtJS image gallery in gridpanel

Tags: extjs

I am struggling how to show multiple columns in gridpanel. 
Currently I have single column, where I show all images which are stored.
The question is, how I can display for example 3 images in same row(decepted ofcourse)?

[Image example](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2eovfhe.jpg)

Columns definition

```
        {id: 'id', header: '#ID', dataIndex: 'id', hidden: true},
        {dataIndex: 'imgPath_server', hidden: true },
        {header: 'PictureName', dataIndex: 'fileName',width:10},
        {header: 'Image', dataIndex: 'fileLocation', renderer: function(a,b){
            var data = Ext.getCmp('<?php echo $treePanel;?>').selModel.selNode.attributes;
             return "<img src='upload/slika_"+data.id+"/"+a+"' atl='"+a+"' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>";
```

Thanks for future assistance! If I wasn't clear I can provide more information.
Greetings!

Comment: So you're saying you won't change how the data looks, but you want to show 3 images, with the same dataIndex name, alongside each other?  Or are you possibly talking about making the grid rows vertical instead of horizontal?

Comment: I want show images with different dataindex. So like 3 in each row. I had tryed with Xtemplate but no success...

Comment: Any idea  how I can apply some style in ExtJS on grid component?

Comment: I really don't understand what the problem is here then... just add two more column headers, and use those dataIndexes for Image2 and Image3.  For styling a grid's component, look into [`componentCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-componentCls)

Comment: As you said this just duplicate the same item. I don't know how to reapeat it with different item. I should break column somehow...